# How can I drop a marker and get a set of lag long within that radius

Tags: leaflet, react-leaflet

My marker is currently draggable with event listener of dragend. I'm able to get that specific point's lag and long, but I want to get the north, south, east and west coordinates.
Im thinking getBound() is what I need but I don't know how to call it in functional React.

Any help much appreciated.

```
import React from 'react';
import { MapContainer, TileLayer, Marker, Popup } from 'react-leaflet'
import "./Map.css"


function Map({children}) {


  return (
      <>
      {children}
      <MapContainer center={[40.678177, -73.944160]} zoom={13} scrollWheelZoom={false}>
        <TileLayer
          attribution='&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
          url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
        />
        <Marker 
          eventHandlers={{
            dragend : (e)=>{
              console.log(e)}
          }}
          draggable={true}
          position={[40.678177, -73.944160]}
          >
          <Popup>
            test
          </Popup>
        </Marker>
      </MapContainer>
      </>
  )
};

export default Map;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A latlng point doesn't have a bounds.  But you can use [leaflet-geometryutil's destination function](https://makinacorpus.github.io/Leaflet.GeometryUtil/global.html#destination) to get points at a certain distance to the north, south, east, and west:

```js
import L from 'leaflet';
import 'leaflet-geometryutil';

const distance = 100 // in meters


// within your component:

eventHandlers={{
  dragend : (e) => {
    const n = L.GeometryUtil.destination(e.latlng, 0, distance)
    const s = L.GeometryUtil.destination(e.latlng, 180, distance)
    const e = L.GeometryUtil.destination(e.latlng, 90, distance)
    const w = L.GeometryUtil.destination(e.latlng, 270, distance)
  }}
```

Now you have points directly north, south, east, and west, exactly `distance` meters from where the dragend event happens.

Comment: Thank you! I didnt know we can import L from "leaflet". I kept going thru React-leaflet's documentation but couldn't find anything!!